# Nginx-watch script - issue with inotifywait not seeing changes

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress

I'm using Nick's excellent [nginx-watch](https://github.com/telephone/nginx-watch) script to monitor an nginx.conf file in www root so that it reloads a couple of wordpress plugin nginx configurations automatically as soon as they change (BWPS and W3TC).

I have it all setup and working except when one of the wordpress plugins modifies the nginx.conf file inotifywait doesn't see the change and thus nginx isn't reloaded.

If I edit the conf file manually it all works perfectly and as expected. I assume it's something to do with the fact that it's the php process modifying the file but I have no idea why inotifywait wouldn't see those changes.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?